# Less, but only last element of every line?

Tags: regular-expression, logs, less, split

So, I want to monitor live logs as they come with less +F, but the logs have a LOT of noise before the actual message - fortunately the line is segmented by | character, with the timestamp being before the first | and the message being after last |

I know it is possible to search with regexes with less - but can you s///g every line and then [-1] element as one would in for eg Perl?

Or maybe there is some completely different way to do it, not using less?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-process the logs before feeding them to `less`:

```
tail -F /path/to/logfile | grep -o '[^|]*$' | less
```

Comment: alas, doesnt work - results in an empty screen
but its a cool idea, perhaps i can work on this

Comment: The filal `less` screws up.